# I am trying to append a return function, error is Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument

Tags: r, return, sapply

I have a sapply line and I want to include a return function so that I can see how far my code is progressing.

When I run this however I return the error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (return(i))
```

The code is:

```
r <- sapply(unique(temp$sim), 
            function(i) optimize(f = eval, interval = c(0, 0.05), df=filter(temp, sim==i))$minimum,return(i))
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The comma between the `...$minimum` and `return (i)` shouldn't be semi-colon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce you since `temp` is not accessible, but the error is probably due to a small typos you made. The `,` between your return and `$minimum` should `;`.

You can try:

```
sapply(unique(temp$sim), function(i) optimize(f = eval, interval = c(0, 0.05), df=filter(temp, sim==i))$minimum; return(i))
```

or better explicitly add the function brackets:

```
sapply(unique(temp$sim), function(i) {
  optimize(f = eval, interval = c(0, 0.05), df=filter(temp, sim==i))$minimum
  return(i)
})
```